# Framework was build without full bitcode

Tags: xcode, kotlin-multiplatform

I have an iOS dynamic framework built using Kotlin Multiplatform. I can successfully link against it, build and run with it. However, when archiving, Xcode throws the error: `ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because '/path/to/framework' was built without full bitcode.`
The following rule is used in our build.gradle.kts file for the framework:

```
iosArm64 {
    binaries {
        framework {
            embedBitcode("bitcode")
        }
    }
}
```

According to other threads, I can check if a framework has bitcode using the following:

```
$ otool -l libName.o | grep __LLVM
```

which yelds:

```
  segname __LLVM
   segname __LLVM
```

That should mean there's bitcode inside.

Does anybody have an idea why Xcode fails to detect bitcode inside the framework?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. Kotlin Multiplatform creates release and debug versions of your targets. The debug version only has bitcode markers while the release version has full bitcode embedded. And I was trying to archive with the debug version of the framework. If I use the release version for archiving, no errors are thrown. The `otool` method only shows if there are markers which are there in both cases.